# He helps people on his fifth grade education

Tags: word-usage

A person was just educated up to fifth grade,  but now he helps a lot of people,  is it okay to say:

> He helps others on his fifth grade education.

Is the use of "on" natural?

Comment: No, it most definitely does not work. With only a fifth-grade education, he etc.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to express with that sentence? I can think of three interpretations: (1) *Now that he has a fifth grade education, he helps others.* (2) *He helps others who have a fifth grade education.* (3) *He helps others to get to a fifth grade education.* The sentence as it's written is both ambiguous and not natural. But without knowing what you're trying to express, I can't comment on the use of *on*.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not clear what you mean.

Either:

> He helps others, despite only getting a fifth grade education.

or

> He helps others because he has a fifth grade education

or something else. It may be worth mentioning that the Grade system is American, and not a universal part of English. (Fifth grade is year 6 in England, something else in Scotland etc) "Primary education" or "elementary education" is more universal.